# How to translate language Using Bing Api in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, bing-api, machine-translation

I am newbie in iOS I make an application that contain Language translate feature, so I use Bing API for it and use [FGTranslator](https://github.com/ashishgabani/FGTranslator) from Github.

But it translate French to English but I want to make an selection to user like as user can select language like as `French`,`Spanish` etc then how convert language from english to Spanish form [FGTranslator](https://github.com/ashishgabani/FGTranslator) Please give me Solution for it.

Here `FGTranslator` language converter method look like as

```
[self.translator translateText:@"Helo How are You"
               completion:^(NSError *error, NSString *translated, NSString *sourceLanguage)
{
     if (error)
     {
         [self showErrorWithError:error];

         [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
     }
     else
     {
         NSString *fromLanguage = [[self currentLocale] displayNameForKey:NSLocaleIdentifier value:sourceLanguage];
         UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:fromLanguage ? [NSString stringWithFormat:@"from %@", fromLanguage] : nil
                                                         message:translated
                                                        delegate:nil
                                               cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                               otherButtonTitles:nil];
         [alert show];
         NSLog(@"STERING %@",translated);
         [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
     }
 }];
```

Here how I can set different language from user selection.

Here i write a method for it then i got error like as `FGTranslatorErrorDomainerror 1`.
Please help me 
I write a method like as

```
[self.translator translateText:self.textView.text withSource:@"en" target:@"js" completion:^(NSError *error, NSString *translated, NSString *sourceLanguage) {

     if (error)
     {
         [self showErrorWithError:error];
         [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
     }
     else
     {
         NSLog(@"Translated Text %@",translated);
    }
 }];
```

Here i write `en` for english and `js` for Japanese Please help me.

Comment: There's a different function for that. Did you read the [reference](https://github.com/ashishgabani/FGTranslator#specify-source-or-target-language)?

Comment: @FabioPoloni yes i know that but it not working for me.

Comment: Why? There's no other (official) way to do this.

Comment: @FabioPoloni can i use this method `- (void)translateText:(NSString *)text
           withSource:(NSString *)source
               target:(NSString *)target
           completion:(NSError *error, NSString *translated, NSString *sourceLanguage)completion;` for it?

Comment: Yes, that's what I wanted to show you with my link to the reference. `- (void)supportedLanguages:` will help to determine the name of the languages.

Comment: @FabioPoloni i not idea to implement that method can you please explain me? thank you.

Comment: There's a parameter for the source and a parameter for the target language. See [Calling Methods](http://cocoadevcentral.com/d/learn_objectivec/)

Comment: @FabioPoloni please show my edited question i implement method but i got error.

Comment: What does `- (void)supportedLanguages:` return?

Comment: @FabioPoloni it return languages Name.like as `English,Japanese, etc`. i also write in my code at the place of `en` `English` and `js` to `Japanese` but same error is occurred.

Comment: So try to give "English" and "Japanese" as the parameter instead of "en" and "js".

Comment: @FabioPoloni i ty it but same error is occurred.

Comment: The error may be a network error…

Comment: @FabioPoloni no network is available and when i try first method i mean`- (void)translateText:(NSString *)text
           completion:(FGTranslatorCompletionHandler)completion` then i got output so network error is not i think.

Comment: @FabioPoloni thanks for help it is working for `English` to `French` thank you.

Comment: I added the correct answer for you to accept. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you're using the wrong name for the translation. The method `supportedLanguages:` returns languages like `English`, `French` and so on, but you're using `en` and `fr` to translate them.

So this should work:

```
[self.translator translateText:self.textView.text withSource:@"English" target:@"French" completion:^(NSError *error, NSString *translated, NSString *sourceLanguage) { /* ... */ }];
```